# SQL Command to copy data from 1 column in table and 1 column in another table into a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had to make a new table to get the Include statement working in Entity Framework since EF was looking for a table called `be_PostTagbe_Posts`. I was using EF Code First from DB. But now the question is about SQL. I added one row of data and now the include works. But what I am looking for is a SQL command that can copy data from 1 column in 1 table and 1 column in another into the new `be_PostTagbe_Posts` table. In the be_Posts table I need the data in `PostRowID` to go into `be_Posts_PostRowID` and `PostTagId` to go into `be_PostTag_PostTagID`. Both `be_PostTag_PostTagID` and `be_Posts_PostRowID` are in the new `be_PostTagbe_Posts` table. I am not very good with SQL so not sure how to do this.

Edit: Thanks for the answers. I tried 2 separate queries but only data was inserted into the the `be_PostTag_PostTagID` while `be_PostTag_PostRowID` remained null.

And I tried this query which returned `The multi-part identifier "be_PostTag.PostID" could not be bound.`

```
INSERT INTO be_PostTagbe_Posts(be_PostTag_PostTagID, be_Posts_PostRowID)
SELECT be_PostTag.PostTagID, be_Posts.PostRowID
WHERE be_PostTag.PostID = be_Posts.PostID
```

EDIT: 
This only inserted half the data - even 2 inserts leave one column null

```
  INSERT INTO be_PostTagbe_Posts (be_Posts_PostRowID)
  SELECT PostRowID FROM be_Posts;
  INSERT INTO be_PostTagbe_Posts (be_PostTag_PostTagID)
  SELECT PostTagID FROM be_PostTag;
```

And yet management studio tells me the query executed successfully but one column is still null. Weird.

Here are screenshots of the tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PostTagID AS be_PostTag_PostTagID, PostRowID AS be_Posts_PostRowID
INTO be_PostTagbe_Posts
FROM be_PostTag
Inner JOIN be_Posts
ON be_PostTag.PostID=be_Posts.PostID
```

That command created the new table with the 2 columns populated.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you ,you want to Copy `Table Z's Column A` to `Table X` And `Table Z's Column B` to `Table Y`.

If it is so, According to your question it is not clear about Table Structure of `TableX` and `TableY`

Assuming `TableX` And `TableY` to single ColumnTable [Apart from IdentityColumn] our query will be

```
INSERT INTO TableX
  SELECT ColumnA FROM TableZ
INSERT INTO TableY
  SELECT ColumnB FROM TableZ
```

Rest put your Entire Structure of Table To Get More Help Because These query are on Assumptions

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your question to give you a working example, but this would be the general syntax for INSERTing into a different table using a query SELECTing from two other tables.

```
INSERT INTO destination_table(wanted_value_1, wanted_value_2)
SELECT table_1.source_field_1, table_2.source_field_1
WHERE table_1.matching_field = table_2.matching_field
```

There has to be some sort of relationship between the two tables for the WHERE clause to work in that statement. I'm guessing based the little information you provided that there is a PostRowID field somewhere in the table that contains the tags such that your data would look similar to this in the tag table:

```
    PostRowID  PostTagID
    ---------  ---------
            1          1
            1          2
            1          3
            1          4
            2          1
            2          2
            3          3
            4          4
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use two sql statements:

```
Insert into `be_PostTagbe_Posts` (`be_PostTag_PostTagID`)
select `PostTagID` from POSTTAGIDTABLE
```

and

```
Insert into `be_PostTagbe_Posts` (`be_Posts_PostRowID`) 
select `PostRowID` from POSTTAGIDTABLE
```

unless the items have some sort of relationship, then if you have a select statement that will select the merged data in two columns you can just do

```
Insert into `be_PostTagbe_Posts` (`be_PostTag_PostTagID`,`be_Posts_PostRowID`)
(select statement that selects the two items)
```